# Polar stereographic projection to regular lat/lon grid

Tags: python, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap, nco, cdo-climate

This is a follow on from my previous question, in that this is much more specific with examples and data. I have a 304 by 448 array of ice data (in polar stereographic projection), of which the netcdf can be obtained [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApWaJaYUUERKjqAxv-o8m2_QloFURA). The corresponding lat/lon points of each grid box can be found in this [file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApWaJaYUUERKjqAyamPgIuanhe9YYQ). I would like to transform this data onto a regular lat/lon grid (say 180x360) where each grid box is a degree. Is there any python way of doing this? Etc using Basemap, or alternatively using CDO (climate data operators)?

Many thanks in advance.
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first add the grid to the data file with, e.g.,

```
ncks -A -v lat,lon NSIDC_LatLon.nc sample.nc
```

Then you can use NCO's [ncremap](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncremap) to regrid that with, e.g.,

```
ncremap -i sample.nc -d 1x1.nc -o out.nc
```

Unfortunately this will require the current snapshot of NCO (rather than a released version) because the input files contained dimensions in an unusual order that I just patched NCO to handle. A sample of the regridded output is [here](http://dust.ess.uci.edu/tmp/out.nc).

At the OP's request I regridded his file then uploaded it ([here](http://dust.ess.uci.edu/tmp/NSIDC_1x1.nc)). I didn't have a 1x1 dataset sitting around so I first created a 1x1 grid file as shown in the manual, then regridded with that (with ncremap -g option):

```
ncremap -i ~/NSIDC.nc -g ${DATA}/grids/180x360_SCRIP.20150901.nc -o ~/NSIDC_1x1.nc
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Is there a way I can obtain this latest snapshot of NCO (as a tar.gz file) so I can implement this solution early on? Thanks.

Comment: Also, what is the 1x1.nc file?

Comment: As the docs explain, 1x1.nc is any file already on the desired 1x1 grid. It will be read, but not written to. NCO is on GitHub. The NCO homepage explains how to clone/obtain the latest snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for undertaking this. Looking out the output it doesn't look right - ice values in the southern hemisphere where there shouldn't be any data. Not sure what went wrong!

Comment: I noticed this too. Your particular use-case requires generating mapping weights from an inexact grid, i.e., the input data has cell centers but no boundaries. ncremap does the best it can to guess the boundaries. Then the weight generator does a pretty good, though not perfect job, generating weights. The southern hemisphere ice is clearly an artifact of the regridding which by default uses a bilinear algorithm. You might consider examing the product produced by applying the conservative regridding algorithm, which I have just uploaded to the original location.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the command to do this in CDO would be

```
cdo remapcon,r360x180 in.nc out.nc
```

instead of con=conservative remapping, you can use bil=bilinear, nn=nearest neighbour, con2=2nd order conservative remapping.

According to this posting, https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/8302?r=8326 the latest versions of cdo should be able to handle polar stereographic projections.